# How to consume REST service created in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest, service

I created a rest service in salesforce as below:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/accounts/*')
global with sharing class REST_Account_Service_V1{

    @HttpGet
    global static Account doGet(){
       RestRequest req=RestContext.request;

       Account result=[select Id,Name,Phone,Website FROM Account limit 1];
       return result;
      } 
}
```

Now I want to consume this REST service in SOAP UI, I did not find any wsdl file for this REST Service in salesforce. I also tried to test this REST service via workbench(https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) but it is asking for production or sandbox login,I have only developer edition.
Please suggest some other tools to consume and test REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its developer edition then please select production as an option in Workbench.
Once you successfully login then follow below steps

1. Click Utilities --> Rest Explorer.
2. Select Get
3. Your URL should be :- /services/apexrest/v1/accounts